# Extract top 5 url based on their associated values (score)?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop a formula that can sort my data with different categories based on several conditions.

Here's my data and the result i'm looking for: -

[image: Data and result]

-

My urls contains "car" or "banana" AND "1" or "2" so i need to sort it with those categories :

- Banana -1
- Banana - 2
- Car - 1
- Car - 2

And I need to sort it by desc, based on the score of each URLs.

It's been a day i'm working on it and I still can't figure it out :(

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration!

Comment: What have you tried please? Please include your code/formula(s) and explain what isn't working. Including the column and row headers is helpful when posting images. Including data, not as an image, but using a tool like a [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) is much more useful as we can copy data for testing and it is properly formatted as well.

Comment: I say instead of sorting it, you just [merge banana and car together](http://themutantbrothers.com/mutant-brothers-vehicles/images/vehicle_top_pic_inner_banana-car.png)

Comment: I've updated my image with column and row ;)
I have tried several conditions with LARGE formula that returns the content of a cells if it contains the biggest value.
I've already deleted the old formula but the latest i've tried was something like this : =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(LOOKUP(banana);"URL");OR(LARGE("score";1);OR((LARGE("score";1)...